# How can I get files from /public directory?

Tags: parse-platform

Subject. I have an app with several static files. I want to get all hosted static files. How can I do It?

Comment: Can you give more details about used technologies?

Answer (score 0):

what does use your web app as technology?
if it's on node.js you can do it with express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/public', express.static(__folder_on__your__app__who_deserve__it__));
```